# How can I encode and decode a string for usage in query string?

Tags: java, jsf, url-encoding

How do I represent a query string in jsf?

I have a query string similar to the below.

> .../faces/WPages/Nav/Catalog.xhtml?Storeid=1&Categoryid=1005&drilldownproperty1=drilldownpropertyval1&drilldownproperty2=drilldownpropertyval2&drilldownproperty3=drilldownpropertyval3& ...

I would like to represent the params

```
drilldownproperty1=drilldownpropertyval1&drilldownproperty2=drilldownpropertyval2&drilldownproperty3=drilldownpropertyval3 ...
```

with something like:

```
drilldownproperty=drilldownpropertyvals
```

where `drilldownpropertyvals` represents `drilldownproperty1=drilldownpropertyval1&drilldownproperty2=drilldownpropertyval2&drilldownproperty3=drilldownpropertyval3`

How can I encode and decode the string before and after performing the url redirect on my managebean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [`java.net.URLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) and [`java.net.URLDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) for.

```
String url = "some.xhtml?drilldownproperty=" + URLEncoder.encode(drilldownpropertyvals, "UTF-8");
```

And then on the other side

```
String drilldownpropertyvals = URLDecoder.decode(drilldownproperty, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a straightforward solution.